# Detecting which button click from previous view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, segue

I have two view controllers "SortViewController" and "CatalogeViewController".
I have on "SortViewController" 6 Button which connected with push segue to "CatalogeViewController"
how can i know from which one of the button the user came from?
I set an identifier for the segue and I have thought about prepare for segue and sending an string variable to "CatalogeViewController" while the user press on button and to check if it the same string on "CatalogeViewController".
There is another way to do that?
and please some one can explain me how to do preapre for segue with string variable according to my question.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bouabane's answer would work, but it would require creating a different segue for each button, which is a lot more work initially, harder to maintain, and clutters your storyboard with lots of segue connections.

Since all of your buttons link to the same destination, I would do it differently.

Create a segue manually by control-dragging from your first VC (ViewController) to your second VC. Give it a unique identifier like "ButtonSegue"

Then create an IBAction for all of your buttons. Link all of your buttons to the same action.

Give each button a unique tag number. Use a sequential range of numbers (e.g. 101, 102... 106).

In your IBAction method, save the button's tag number to an instance variable.

In your prepareForSegue, pass the tag number instance variable to your destination VC. (The code to match a number is faster and simpler than the code to match strings. With numbers you can use a switch statement.)

To make the code cleaner and easier to read, I would define a typedef'd enum with the possible tag values, then make your source view controller's tag number instance variable and your destination view controller's tag number property use that type.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this method.

> -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

This is an example how you can accomplish your need:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

 CatalogeViewController *catalogeViewController = segue.destinationViewController;;
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"firtsSegue"])
{
   catalogeViewController.selectedButton = @"firstButton";
}else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"secondSegue"]){
   catalogeViewController.selectedButton = @"secondButton";
}else
 .
 .
 .
}
```